# Can't export more than 2 lines to the csv

Tags: oracle, powershell

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Oracle.DataAccess")

$username = "USER"
$password = "PW"
$datasource = "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:YYYY/NODE1"

function getConnectionString()
{
    #Below is a one line code
    $connectionstring = "Data Source=$datasource;User Id=$($username); Password=$($password)"
    return $connectionstring
}
$query = get-content "C:\Test.sql";
$connectionstring = getConnectionString
$DataTable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
$command = New-Object Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand($query,$connectionstring)
$dataAdapter = New-Object Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataAdapter($command)
[void]$dataAdapter.Fill($DataTable)
#To display data on console
$DataTable | format-table -auto
#To export to csv
$DataTable | Export-Csv "C:\Test.csv" -notype
```

The "Test.sql contains:

```
SELECT ACCOUNTNUMBER, ACCOUNTID, USERID FROM account
WHERE ACCOUNTNUMBERLIKE '%0011111%'
```

That quesy brings back 3 rows.

Issue at hand: My powershell script only gives me the first 2 rows (1 being the headers, the other being the first data row)

Any advice?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but you dont parse any variables into `getConnectionString()` which lets the variables `$datasource` , $username` and `$password` be emtpty in the function.

Comment: Huh, really? I've tested it the way they are set up right now and it's worked with different data sources.

Comment: @Paxz - It isn't best standards but in this instance the Global variables would be used.

Comment: Well TIL that this seems to be standard behaviour in powershell then, I allways though it had to be defined via $global:<variable>. Thx @EBGreen

Comment: Doing that would force a global variable to be used if there were another variable with the same name in a more local scope.

Comment: What'd you suggest I change that to, to follow a good standard? @EBGreen

Comment: You should pass parameters in to the function rather than rely on the existence of global variables. It reduces coupling and improves code maintainability.

Comment: I just tested your code with changes to userid/password. I changed the select statement to **select * from sys.global_name union all select * from dual  union all select * from global_name**. I received all three records, with the column name.

Comment: not quite sure, but isn't the `DataAdapter.Fill()` not designed to fill a dataSet rather that a dataTable? Then use `$dataset.Tables[0] | Export-CSV "C:\Test.csv" -notype`. Have a look here https://powershellreflections.wordpress.com/2011/02/14/using-powershsell-to-access-sql-data/